# Wave equation (in vacuum) solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Even if it seems like a physics-related topic it really isn't. If we observe the electromagnetic wave equation in vacuum, the homogeneous case, we have the following partial 2nd order differential equations:

$$(\triangle - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac {\partial^2}{\partial t^2})\vec E(\vec r, t)=0$$

The solutions to this are the following: $$\vec E(\vec r, t) = \vec E_0e^{i(\vec k \vec r - \omega t)}$$.

In most books or site online, there is no proper derivation of the solution. I really would like to know how we come up with this result. Because later on we find (in physics) that $\vec k$ is the wave vector, whose direction is the direction in which the wave propagates.

Comment: Are you talking about $$\left(\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac {\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\vec E(\vec r, t)=0$$ or something different? It would be helpful to readers if you precisely defined the symbols that you use? Where is the magnetic wave? The electric and magnetic waves go as a pair in physics.  Please explain why for vague "mathematical" reasons you want to study one without the other.

Comment: It is _a_ solution, which you may easily derive by separation of the variables. Unless some initial/boundary conditions are imposed, nobody claims that it is _the_ solution. As _a_ solution it is quite instrumental in the develoment of the theory.

Comment: @JamesArathoon I am simply focusing in the electric wave. The general idea is how do i solve this equation. It doesn't have to be a wave at all. It can simply be a function f(x,t).

Comment: This problem should be posed more clearly. Is $\vec{E}$ vector-valued? If so, how are you defining the PDEs (e.g. are the operators simply acting component-wise). Really, this just them checking a single Fourier mode which is often done to establish e.g. dispersive relations.